# How resize a long table? (scalebox doesn't work)

Tags: tables, longtable, resize, scale

I am writing to you because I would like to resize a long rotated table but `\scalebox` command does not work.
Here is an example of my input:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.5}{!}{\input{table}}
\end{document}
```

and the table is:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{@{}llllllllllllllll@{}}
    \toprule
    & AA & BB & CC & DD & EE & FF & GG & HH & II & JJ & KK & LL & MM & NN & OO \\*  \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \endlastfoot
    %
    A & 0  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
    B & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
    C & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
    D & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
    A & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
    B & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
    C & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
    D & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 \\
    A & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 \\
    B & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \\
    C & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    D & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \\
    A & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    B & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 \\
    C & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 \\
    D & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 \\
    A & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 \\
    B & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 \\
    C & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 \\
    D & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 \\
    A & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
    B & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
    C & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 \\
    D & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 \\
    A & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 \\
    B & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 \\
    C & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 \\
    D & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 \\
    A & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 \\
    B & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 \\
    C & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 \\
    D & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 \\
    A & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 \\
    B & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 \\
    C & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 \\
    D & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 \\
    A & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\
    B & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 \\
    C & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 \\
    D & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 \\* \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

I am able to compile my LaTeX input correctly but the table remains the same size.
Unfortunately I need to divide the table into two pages and rotate it because it is very long. Could anyone help me?

EDIT: For greater precision I specify that I would like to fit the ENTIRE table in the sheet of my document.

Comment: Wekcome to TeX SX! Anyway, `\scalebox`  shouldn't be used for tables, as it leads to  inconsistent font sizes. You van play with the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default), use a smaller font size or use the `landscape`  environment.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the welcome. I am already using the `landscape` environment and am also rotating the table. I am also using the smaller character (`\scriptsize`) but the table does not fit into the sheet for a while. So, I would like to shrink it to scale to fit into the sheet.

Comment: If setting, say, `tabcolsep`  to 2pt is not enough,  probably you  should think of redesigning you (real) table.

Comment: Yep, I'm considering this. But isn't there a way to scale the size of a table?

Comment: For a normal table (I mean, not a longtable), you can use  \adjustbox, but  this should really be used as a last resort.

Comment: Let me add another possibility: if the table is too wide because of cells contents, you can use multilined cells with the p, m,b, X specifiers in the table preamble, or, if the problem comes from some specific cells, you can use the `makecell` package, and its eponymous command to set manual line breaks in standard columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you're trying tp achieve. I will assume that you're trying to fit the `longtable` in the width of the textblook, *without* having to switch to landscape mode. This may be achieved, for the table at hand, by taking an approach that's mentioned on page 7 of the user guide of the `longtable` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
% make 'longtable' behave like 'tabular*'
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{15}{c} }
    \toprule
    & AA & BB & CC & DD & EE & FF & GG & HH & II & JJ & KK & LL & MM & NN & OO \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \endhead

    \bottomrule
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    A & 0  & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
    B & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
    C & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
    \dots\\
    D & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 \\*
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. What I want to achieve is that to fit the ENTIRE table in the pages of my document. Your suggestion could be an alternative but I want to do what I can to insert the entire table.

Comment: @zcbcpaoa - Is something stopping you from inserting a `\small` directive after `\begingroup`?

Comment: I am already using the smallest font `\scriptsize` and the table does not fit into the sheet for a while. I need to scale my table (let's say 20%)